# Iterating through GridView Rows and setting image individually

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, xtraeditors

I have a Devexpress DataGridView.A column named TEST is set to display an image using `RepositoryItemTextEdit`

```
 RepositoryItemTextEdit te = new RepositoryItemTextEdit();
 _grd.RepositoryItems.Add(te);
 _rgv.Columns["TEST"].ColumnEdit = te;
 te.ContextImage = myimage;
```

This code sets the image for all cells in the column.How can i individually edit the cell images in a loop?

Comment: Better then loop isnt there a row initialized or column initialized event where you can set it at individual cell level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a limited number of images, I would recommend creating a few repository items and assign them to cells conditionally in the [GridView](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView).[CustomRowCellEdit](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CustomRowCellEdit) event.

If you need to have a number of different images, use one of the approaches described in the [Cell Icons](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/643/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/views/grid-view/cells#icons) section of the [Cells](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/643/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/views/grid-view/cells) article.

Comment: Thanks.. is there any way to have two separate views ie: the original string data in each cell ,then another view ie: render view that renders the data based on the data in the original view.

Comment: sure. You can add a view to [GridControl](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl._members).[ViewCollection](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.ViewCollection) and then switch them via [MainView](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.MainView)

Answer (score 2):

Handle `CustomDrawCell` event.

```
private void _grd_CustomDrawCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Column.FieldName == "TEST") {
    var te = (e.Cell as GridCellInfo).ViewInfo as TextEditViewInfo;
    te.ContextImage = GetCustomImageForThisRow(); // <-- your custom logic 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... if i use this approach.. can i get the original string value stored there?

Comment: I mean after i replace it with an Image(TextEditor)?